# Integrate $\int\Big(\sqrt{4x^2+9-4x}\Big)^3\,dx$ by using trigonometric substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Hello I was wondering if I could have some assistance on integrating the following integral using trigonometric substitution.
$$\int\Big(\sqrt{4x^2+9-4x}\Big)^3\,dx.$$

Comment: Doesn't look simple http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%284x%5E2-4x%2B9%29%5E%283%2F2%29

Comment: At which part are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: So i started by completing the square, and from there i am not sure, how i would set my x=to im struggling with this kind of integration since i am not very good at it.

Comment: @CarlosV What expression did you produce by completing the square? The form of the result will always tell you which kind of substitution to make. (In fact, for any integral of the form $\int P(\sqrt{a x^2 + b x + c}) dx$, where $P$ is a polynomial, the discriminant $b^2 - 4 a c$ of the quadratic tells you ahead of time which trig/hyperbolic trig function you'll need.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no activity in ten days, with outstanding questions to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $4x^2-4x+9=(2x-1)^2+8$.

So now put $2x-1=2\sqrt 2\tan\theta$

Then our integrand becomes $8\sqrt 2\sec^5\theta d\theta$

Can you do the integration now?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Completing the square $$4x^2-4x+9=4\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2+8$$ So, make the change of variable $$x=\frac 12+\sqrt 2 \sinh(y),\quad dx=\sqrt 2 \cosh(y)dy$$ and simplify. You should get to a quite simple expression.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 2):

$$4x^2+4x+9=(2x+1)^2+8\\2x+1:=\sqrt 8 \sinh t\Rightarrow I=32\int\cosh^4t\,\,dt=32\int\cosh^2t(1+\sinh^2t)\,\,dt=32\int{{(1+\cosh2t)}\over 2}+{1\over 8}(\cosh4t-1)\,\,dt={3\over 8}t+{1\over 4}\sinh 2t+{1\over 32}\sinh 4t$$